# concatenate the strings separated by comma but if the string is empty comma should not be in the beginning

Tags: php

I have 3 strings:

```
$string1=1,2,3,4,5,6
$string2=7,8,9
$string3=11,12
```

I want to concatenate the above strings separated by comma.

Desired Output:

```
$string=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12
```

Since  above all are string i cannot use `IMPLODE()` also i cannot use `(.)` concatenation operator as i want the strings to be separated by `(,)` i.e. comma.

```
$string = $string1 . "," . $string2 . "," . $string3;
```

thanks to everyone that i got the solution but any of the above strings can be empty also.that means if $string 1 is empty than i will have

```
$string =,7,8,9,11,12
```

but in any case I **can't afford a comma in the beginning**.

than the output should be

```
$string =7,8,9,11,12
```

how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: And all these variables are strings, not arrays?

Comment: Try this : echo implode(',', array_filter(array( $string1,$string2,$string3)));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plain contatenation should work fine:

```
$string = $string1 . "," . $string2 . "," . $string3;
```

or more compact:

```
$string = "{$string1},{$string2},{$string3}";
```

And you **can** use `implode()` but you need to first `explode(',', $string1);`. Still, plain concatenation is perfectly sufficient according to your description.

**EDIT**

> cant afford a comma in the begining.

then remove it:

```
if( $string[0] === ',' ) {
   $string = substr($string,1);
}
```

Comment: sometimes things can be so simple,i thought of all the complex approach but this one didnot cross my mind.:) thanks +1 will accept it after a while

Comment: Do not worry. Happens to everyone from time to time :)

Comment: Is this really the level of questions, that should be answered by a user with 18k reputation. Don't you have **any** pride?

Comment: I will be answering questions as I like, regardless of my rank. Feel free to avoid such question if you got problems with your "pride"...

Comment: @tereško i think you have around 27k reputation in 3 years that means 9k reputation per year ,mine is around 2k in less than 2 months so you can calculate that for 3 years .we all start from some place and we learn from our mistakes and we all do silly mistakes.with knowledge should come politeness.

Comment: see edited answer. Still, try to be bit more creative yourself too :)

Comment: i think this might create a problem if there is a string like **3, ,4,5**

Comment: yes it will. The best approach is to explode/implode. The simplest approach is `preg_replace()` multiple comas with one

Answer (score 2):

```
$string=$string1.",".$string2.",".$string3;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$del = ',';
$res = array_merge(explode ( $del , $string1 ),explode ( $del , $string2 ),explode ( $del , $string3 )); 
var_dump(implode($del,$res));
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer has already been given but i think this one also suits your all **requirements very well.** It will work if there is a comma in starting,end or in between.I hope so :)

```
public function verywell()
{
    $string1='1,2,3,4,5,6,,,,,,,';
    $string2=',,,,,,,,7,,9';
    $string3='10,11,,,,,,,,12';
    $arr1=  explode(',', $string1);
    $arr2=  explode(',', $string2);
    $arr3=  explode(',', $string3);
    $val=  array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);
    foreach($val as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($value=='')
        {
            unset($val[$key]);

        }
    }
       echo implode(',',$val);
}
```

Comment: why not use array_unique?

Comment: because a string might have duplicate values like 3,3,4,5,6